# How to work with Sharepoint cmdlet without installing sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0, sharepointadmin

I have to upload csv file fields into Sharepoint 2010 list using powershell. I am working in windows XP machine.

When i am trying to add-pssnapin

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

It throws exception as

> "The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell' is
>   not installed on this machine."

Is it possible to work with Sharepoint Powershell cmdlet just by installing Pssnapin or by placing the necessary dlls in some location and load it?

Comment: Essentially duplicated by http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/how-do-i-install-the-2013-sharepoint-powershell-module-on-my-windows-7-client-co but can't flag it as such when it is on a different Stack site.

Answer (score 5):

I think the only way is to `Enable-PSRemoting` on Sharepoint server, then from XP computer:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName sharepointservername
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

In this way you can manage remotely your sharepoint server

Edit:

[Sharepoint Remoting step by step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step.aspx)